# Is 目を覚ます being used in a personification-style manner in these lyrics?

Tags: meaning, translation

these are the lyrics-

```
胃がもたれるような不快感    
Nightmareに目を覚ます
```

Should I treat 胃がもたれるような不快感 like a "floating" noun and translate this as-

```
Discomfort that feels like an upset stomach 
Because of a Nightmare, I wake up
```

Or is the 不快感 being personified and the translation should be-

```
Discomfort that feels like an upset stomach
Wakes up because of a nightmare
```

I tried to find examples of 目を覚ます being used for subjects other than humans but could not, so I feel like this second one is wrong.

If the first one is correct, can I translate it sort of like this to fix the "floating" noun issue?

```
My discomfort feels like an upset stomach
```

I would greatly appreciate any feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

目を覚ます can figuratively take an inanimate subject in creative writing; for example we can find examples like [寂しさが目を覚ます](https://www.uta-net.com/song/296404/), [閉じた傷が目を覚ます](https://www.uta-net.com/song/295419/), [闇が目を覚ます](https://www.uta-net.com/song/280447/) and [月が目を覚ます](https://www.uta-net.com/song/289073/).

That being said, unless there is clearly が after 不快感, I certainly interpret the first line as an independent "floating noun phrase". 不快感 doesn't have a dream, after all. The subject of 目を覚ます in this song should be implicit "I".

Comment: Thank you so much, this line was giving me trouble for so long. Do you think I can translate the 不快感 line as "My discomfort feels like an upset stomach."? I don't mind how the current version sounds, but is this version also an option?

Comment: @MastahxGraffiti How about "an uneasiness/discomfort that upsets/turns my stomach"?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I think your translation works too, I was just wondering if the line could be rephrased in this specific case.

Comment: @MastahxGraffiti The simplest approach should be "there is discomfort" or "I feel discomfort", but your translation seems okay to me, too.